# Rails form with three models and namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, namespaces, associations

Banging my head against this one for a long time. On Rails 2.3.2, Ruby 1.9.1.

Trying to use one form to create three objects that have these relations:

```
class Person
  has_one :goat
end

class Goat
  belongs_to :person
  has_many :kids
end

class Goat::Kid
  belongs_to :goat
end
```

Here's a summary of the schema:

```
Person
  first_name
  last_name
Goat
  name
  color
Goat::Kid
  nickname
  age
```

I'd like my `#create` action to instantiate new instances of all three models with the specified associations. However, while it appears that my params hash is being passed to the controller as it should (based on the backtrace logs in the browser when it blows up), the `Goat::Kid` object is not collecting the params.

irb (irb session is just a psuedo-representation of what I'm trying to accomplish so if it doesn't call `#save!` or any other necessities it's not really meant to be correct. I'm trying to do this all through the browser/web form.)

```
a = Person.new :first_name => 'Leopold', :last_name => 'Bloom'
b = Goat.new :name => 'Billy', :color => 'white'
c = Goat::Kid.new :nickname => 'Jr.', :age => 2

a.goat.kids

>> []
```

Now, I cannot figure out how to get the view to pass the params to each object and to get the controller to save these params to the db.

My questions: A) is this a good place to use `nested_attributes_for` and if so how do I declare that with a namespace? B) is there a much simpler, easier to understand way to do this?

Passing params to three models has just been very challenging to me and no matter how much documentation I read I can't wrap my head around it (`#form_for` and `#fields_for`).  The namespace further complexifies this. Thanks for any help!

---

Addendum: if I end up declaring

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for
```

what's the proper way to use the symbol argument for a namespaced model?

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :kids, :through => :goats
```

or

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :goats_kids, :through => :goats
```

or

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :goats::kids, :through => :goats
```

I'm not sure how namespaced models translate to their symbol identifiers.  Thanks!

Comment: Well, not sure that was too clear. Here's how I'd like my form to look: <br />Person First Name: <br />Person Last Name: <br />Goat Name: <br />Goat Color: <br />Goat::Kid Nickname: <br />Goat::Kid Age: <br />So, this one form would create three new models with the appropriate associations and namespace considerations. eek.

Comment: Yes, this is for the forthcoming Goatr app. No, these models are fictitious to protect the innocent. This was the only example I could think of using a namespace--it makes sense though right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this is my first time playing with `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, but with a little playing around I was able to get something to work.

First the model setup:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :goat
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :goat
end

class Goat < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  has_many :kids

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :kids
end

class Goat::Kid < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :goat
end
```

With a simple restful controller:

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.resources :farm
end

class FarmController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    person = Person.new params[:person]
    person.save
    render :text => person.inspect
  end
end
```

Then comes the semi-complex form:

Next, the form setup:

```
<% form_for :person, :url => farm_index_path do |p| %>
  <%= p.label :first_name %>: <%= p.text_field :first_name %><br />
  <%= p.label :last_name %>: <%= p.text_field :last_name %><br />
  <% p.fields_for :goat_attributes do |g| %>
    <%= g.label :name %>: <%= g.text_field :name %><br />
    <%= g.label :color %>: <%= g.text_field :color %><br />
    <% g.fields_for 'kids_attributes[]', Goat::Kid.new do |k| %>
      <%= k.label :nickname %>: <%= k.text_field :nickname %><br />
      <%= k.label :age %>: <%= k.text_field :age %><br />
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= p.submit %>
<% end %>
```

From looking at the source for `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, it looks like it will create a method for you called `#{attr_name}_attributes=`, so I needed to setup my `fields_for` to reflect that (Rails 2.3.3). Next, getting the `has_many :kids` working with `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. The `kids_attributes=` method was looking for an array of objects, so I needed to specify the array association in the form manually and tell `fields_for` what type of model to use.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Heya, Michael, I appreciate your offering but the implementation threw me a NoMethodError that I don't fully understand--any ideas? I really appreciate it. (I left a comment below because I had trouble logging in to this account)

Comment: Thanks, this is great. The significant thing in my case was the `g.fields_for 'kids_attributes[]', Goat::Kid.new` part.